# Ruby 2.0/ Rails 4.0.0beta upgrade fails on push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Brain dump because mine is fried with googling and slamming my head on the computer. Any help or clues would be GREATLY appreciated!

I manage my gems via rvm.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]

$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0.beta1
```

Then when I want to create a brand new app from scratch

```
$ rails new brand_new_app
 create  
  create  README.rdoc
  ...
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

$ cd brand_new_app
```

Then I initialize a git repo, add the app I just created. I then create a heroku instance

```
brand_new_app $ heroku create
    Git remote heroku added
```

Then I try and deploy to heroku but it fails on the active support gem.

```
brand_new_app $ git push heroku master
    Counting objects: 62, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (62/62), 20.54 KiB, done.
    Total 62 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

    -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
    -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Installing rake (10.0.3)
   Installing i18n (0.6.4)
   Installing minitest (4.6.2)
   Installing multi_json (1.6.1)
   Installing atomic (1.0.1)
   Installing thread_safe (0.1.0)
   Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
   Installing activesupport (4.0.0.beta1)
   Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
   An error occurred while installing activesupport (4.0.0.beta1), and Bundler
   cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '4.0.0.beta1'` succeeds before
   bundling.
     !
     !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
     !
     !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

I have imploded rvm (idk why, mainly bc I was frustrated) and I have checked every place possible. I created the rails app without any special settings, it is just a normal install. If anyone has any hints that could lead me to the right direction, please send them my way! I appreciate you reading this far!

Comment: Are you sure that you're executing on the right stack? You have to use cedar. I'm unsure if the default in the heroku tool right now is that stack or the older bamboo one.

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like? Is there a `ruby` line in it?

Comment: @Srdjan I did double check and it is using cedar, as that is currently the default. Thank you very much for taking the time to look at this!

Comment: @Ari I double checked, and the default rails new did not place a ruby version in the gemfile. I made no modifications to any files in the app btw, all I did was the rails new command. And I also thank you for taking your time out to help me! It is very appreciated!

Comment: hey Ben when you get time you should accept Arjan's answer so he gets the points. It worked for me and helped me out. Thanks for posting!

Comment: @RudyOnRails I completely forgot to accept the answer and thank you very much for reminding me! All the best!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should put a ruby line in your Gemfile like is explained in the heroku documentation.

Just add the line `ruby "2.0.0"` beneath `source "https://rubygems.org"` in your Gemfile.

https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/11/5/ruby-2-preview-on-heroku

I have tried this, and this works for heroku. Apparently Rails 4 is not compatible with different ruby versions. This is kind of odd, since they say here that:

> Ruby 2.0 is the preferred Ruby to use with Rails 4.0.

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/25/Rails-4-0-beta1/

Apparently preferred, means required.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the info Arjan and Ari, and I will take a look at that right now

Comment: Don't forget you have to `git commit` your changes for heroku to acknowledge them. I just spent a real long time figuring that out. Now I'll spend a real long time feeling dumb.